# Marking all positions of occurrences in text

Tags: python, string, data-structures, time-complexity

I have a list of strings, and 2 Lookup tables.

Say,
text: "`Barrack Obama was president of the United States`"

```
LookupA: ["Barrack", "Barrack Obama"]
LookupB: ["United", "United States", "president"]
```

I need a computationally cheap way and *pythonic* way of tagging all occurrences with positions such that,

result: `[("Barrack", 0, "A"), ("Barrack Obama", 0, "A"), ("president", 18, "B"), ("United", 35, "B"), ("United States", 35, "B")]`

I currently have a very inefficient way of handling this. I imagine this can be done quickly using the Tries structure but I don't know how to go about using that in a *pythonic* way over a stream of text. Tagging words at the word (not subword) level will also be enough for my usecase, if it simplifies the problem.

My inefficient code can be found below:

```
annotations_all = []
for text_index, text in enumerate(texts):
    annotations = []
    found_uniq_entities_tup = {}

    for entity in lookupA:
        if entity not in found_uniq_entities_tup:
            start_index = str(text).find(entity)
            if not start_index == -1:
                found_uniq_entities_tup[entity] = 'A'

    for entity in lookupB:
        if entity not in found_uniq_entities_tup:
            start_index = str(text).find(entity)
            if not start_index == -1:
                found_uniq_entities_tup[entity] = 'B'

    def find_all(super_string: str, sub_string: str):
        start = 0
        while True:
            start = super_string.find(sub_string, start)
            if start == -1:
                return
            yield start
            start += len(sub_string)

    # Find all mentions of all found entities
    for key in found_uniq_entities_tup:
        start_index_list = find_all(str(text), str(key))
        for start_index in start_index_list:
            if not start_index == -1:
                annotations.append({"start": start_index, "end": start_index + len(key) - 1, "entity": key,
                                    "label": found_uniq_entities_tup[key]})
    annotations_all.append(annotations)
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and your patience. I have edited to include my currently working but inefficient code which reproduces the output I mentioned in text. Please let me know if this is insufficient; I couldn't find similar questions on stackoverflow

Comment: If you can sort the text in a preprocessing step then you can do binary search and do it in O log n instead of O n. But it becomes more complex, and a lot less readable.

Comment: @shanecandoit Thanks; but some of the lookup entities span multiple words such as "United States". Sorting at a 1-gram/1-word level would mess it up as far as I can see

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression that combines all you keywords and map the matches to a tag dictionary.  The only issue is that some of your keywords contain smaller ones.  This can be handled by producing separate regular expressions for each word count in the keywords and checking the text against each group of patterns.

Example:

```
import re
tags = {"barrack":"A", "barrack obama":"A", 
        "united":"B", "united states":"B", "president":"B"}

patterns = dict()
for tag in tags: # group keywords by number of words
    patterns.setdefault(tag.count(" "),[]).append(tag)
patterns = [re.compile(r"\b("+"|".join(tn)+r")\b",flags=re.I) 
             for tn in patterns.values()] # regular expression for each group

# generator function to find/return tagged words
def tagWords(text):
    for pattern in patterns: # lookup for each keyword group
        for match in pattern.finditer(text):    # go through matches
            word = match.group()                # matched keyword
            pos  = match.start()                # position in string
            yield (word,pos,tags[word.lower()]) # output tagged word
```

output:

```
text = "Barrack Obama was president of the United States"
for tag in tagWords(text): print(tag)
('Barrack', 0, 'A')
('president', 18, 'B')
('United', 35, 'B')
('Barrack Obama', 0, 'A')
('United States', 35, 'B')
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll check the time performance compared to my old solution but so far this appears to be the answer. I'll update accordingly